# How do I read from a serialized array?

Tags: arrays, serialization, boost

When i serialize an individual string. I am able to use it within my code. However when i do the same thing with an array, it just gives me random characters or integers. I want to know a way for how can I read from an archive that contains an array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>


using namespace std;

void CWordSave()
{

    ofstream file("archive.txt");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(file);
    string Cwords[] = { "Oak", "Tree", "Dog", "Cat", "Human", "Food", "Computer", "Inteligent", "Special", "Unique" };

    oa << Cwords;
}

void CWordLoad(int &i)
{

    ifstream file("archive.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(file);
    string Cwords;
    ia >> Cwords;


        cout << Cwords[i] << endl;


}
int main()
{
CWordSave();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {

        CWordLoad(i);

    }

return 0;
}
```

I expected for the contents of the whole array to be printed instead of random integers and characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
string Cwords[] = { "Oak", "Tree", "Dog",
```

is an array, and by

```
oa << Cwords;
```

you serialized the array.

This

```
string Cwords;
```

is one instance of `string`. By `ia >> Cwords;` you deserialized one string object, not array.

In `cout << Cwords[i] << endl;` you are calling `string::operator[]` and you are acccessing individual character of string instead of printing the whole string instances.

When deserializing you have to create array, and you have to ensure its size is enough to store data:

```
string Cwords[10];
ia >> Cwords;
cout << Cwords[i] << endl; // now, this accesses instance of string from array
```

if you want your code to be more flexible maybe you should use vector of string?

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
...
    vector<string> Cwords = { "Oak", "Tree", "Dog", "Cat", "Human", "Food", "Computer", "Inteligent", "Special", "Unique" };
    oa << Cwords;
...
    vector<string> Cwords;
    ia >> Cwords;

    if (i < Cwords.size())
        cout << Cwords[i] << endl;
```